# mysql-cli and mysql-workbench sync not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a simple question..

I created new user in the mysql command line

with the commmand

```
create user user_name@localhost identified by password;
grant all privileges on DB_name.* to user_name@localhost;
flush privileges;
```

but when I turn on the mysql workbench there`s only root user in that application, though new user has been created in the mysql-cli.

what`s wrong..?

Comment: Cli and workbench do not sync. They just merely connect to the same mysql instance.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for your help, so you mean the mysqlbench reflects the new tables and instances but not the new db and user ?

Comment: Nope, I do not mean that.

Comment: @Shadow I will fix.. as of my test result, mysql doesn`t reflect only for new user. right?

Comment: @Shadow but i am still curious of your meaning 'sync'. does not sync means "reflecting schema structure"? but it works..

Comment: @Shadow since i`m new here, can you explain more about that?

Comment: There is nothing to sync.

Comment: thanks. so, is that right what am I understanding?